# Angular: Delete One at a Time instead of All at Once in the Right-Click Menu

Tags: html, angular

I am new to Angular and I am having trouble making my right-click delete function show the delete button one at a time as opposed to all at once in the right-clicked menu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpko1.png)

This is my array of strings

```
account:string[] = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

This is where I performed the right-clicked function

```
<div (contextmenu) = "rightMenu($event)" (click) = "disappearContext()">
    {{ listitem }}
</div>
```

My Right Clicked Function

```
@ViewChild('menu') menu!: ElementRef;rightMenu(e: MouseEvent) {
e.preventDefault();
this.menu.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
this.menu.nativeElement.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
this.menu.nativeElement.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
```

This is where I did delete

```
<div class= "customContext" #menu>
    <ul>
      <div *ngFor = "let listitem of account; let myIndex=index;"><li (click) = "delete(myIndex)">Delete</li></div>      
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And this is my delete function

```
delete(index: number) {
this.account.splice(index, 1);
```

How do I make my right-click menu show one delete at a time as opposed to showing every delete button in the menu at once?